# MS Word master document embedding rather linking subdocuments

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

When I add a subdocument to an MS Word master document using the outlining toolbar, I'm able to toggle the 'Collapse Subdocuments' button to see the hyperlink to the embedded document.  I'm also able to see updates to the text of the subdocument appear within the master.  However, sometime within the next few openings of the Master document, I'll find that the subdocuments can no longer be collapsed to show their links.  They also no longer update.  It appears that Word decided to just copy the text into the master document, and be done with it.  Is there a way to prevent this behavior so I don't have to keep reassembling the master document in vain hope that the this time updates will continue to be incorporated?

Comment: One key seems to be to collapse all subdocuments after adding each new subdocument.  If a 'can't save because of read-only' warning appears, then undo the recent subdocument add, then redo it, and repeat.  For me, every time on the 2nd try, the save will succeed.  Also seems important to only save master with all subdocuments collapsed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a root cause, but the following steps will work around the issue:

First, always save your document with all subdocuments collapsed.

To add more subdocuments:

1. Expand the existing subdocuments.
2. Add your new subdocument.
3. Collapse all subdocuments, (at this point, you should be asked if
   you want to save, click yes).
4. You may or may not receive an error message stating that one of the
   subdocuments is read-only.  Click OK
5. Undo the subdocument insertion using Ctrl-Z
6. Insert the subdocument again
7. Once again collapse all subdocuments and respond yes when asked to save.

The second insertion of the subdocument will not receive the read-only error message.